# Xpages Type Ahead Drop Down font size

Tags: xpages, typeahead, editbox

Is it possible to change the font size of the drop down list that appears in an Xpages type ahead control?

Have to display a type ahead on a 7 inch tablet screen and readability is quite hard for most people.

```
<xp:td><xp:inputText id="inputHost" styleClass="inputCovFieldYellow">
<xp:typeAhead mode="partial" minChars="1" valueList="#{javascript:applicationScope.employeeSelectionListNoNum;}" ignoreCase="true"
 id="typeAhead1"> </xp:typeAhead> </xp:inputText>
```

Comment: You can most certainly change it using CSS. I suggest that you inspect the HTML elements in your browser to see what CSS to change

Comment: I have tried changing the css. But it only changes on the edit box where I enter characters. The drop down that appears after searching through my datalist in the type ahead is still a small font size and is not affected by the css.

Comment: Above is the code I use to declare the type ahead. There is no option to add a styleClass to the type ahead directly only to the edit box that uses it. @PerHenrikLausten

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The xp:typeahead control wraps its content in an outer div with CSS classes dijitPopup and dijitComboBoxMenuPopup, an inner div with CSS classes dijitReset, dijitMenu and dijitComboBoxMenu, and then a div with CSS class dijitMenuItem for each item in the drop down list.

So you can style each item using these classes. Here's a simple example of setting the font size to 20 px:

```
.dijitComboBoxMenu .dijitMenuItem {
    font-size: 20px;
}
```

Comment: Had to add to the theme stylesheet and it worked. Thank you @PerHenrikLausten.